# ImportError : cannot import name AppCache

Tags: django

I have installed `Django 1.8.3` Then i created my project. I need to import the AppCache but not able to import it. In Django shell i wrote

```
from django.db.models.loading import AppCache
```

Error is:

> ImportError: cannot import name AppCache

Please help me out.

Comment: Which is the relevant package? Have you installed it?

Comment: No, I did not installed. It comes by degault with django

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AppCache is not a part of django.db.models.loading from  django 1.7 onwards.For more information you can read this [link](http://andrewsforge.com/article/upgrading-django-to-17/part-3-django-17-new-features/)